# Python - set items on a list to a list of dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given the `list`:

```
links = [ 'link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link3', 'link4', 'link5', 'link6', 'link6', 'link7', 'link8', 'link9', 'link10']
```

and this list of `dicts`:

```
 sources =  [{'src': ''}, {'src': ''}, {'src': ''}, {'src': ''}, {'src': ''}, {'src': ''}, {'src': ''}, {'src': ''}, {'src': ''}, {'src': ''}]
```

I would like to set each `src` value to its correspondant link, like so:

`{'src': 'link1'}, {'src': 'link2'}`...

I have tried:

```
for s in sources:
    for l in links:
        s['src'] = l
        print (s)
```

but this does the job 10 times, and I'd like to have it done only once.

How can I achieve this with a one-liner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume there's something else in `src` dicts, otherwise `sources` would make little sense:

```
for src, link in zip(sources, links):
    src['src'] = link
```

It is possible to write that as one-liner:

```
[s.update({'src': x }) for s, x in zip(sources, links)]
```

but this would be a so-called "comprehension with side effects" and considered bad taste by most pythonistas. A loop is far more pythonic.

The above also assumes that `len(sources)==len(links)` otherwise consider:

```
for src, link in zip(sources, itertools.cycle(links)):
    src['src'] = link
```

which will populate links in a round-robin fashion.

If these `src` dicts are actually empty, there's no need to keep a list of them, just create it from the scratch:

```
 sources = [{'src': x} for x in links]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not rcecommend a one-liner here.  Just a simple for-loop is best:

```
>>> for d,link in zip(sources, links):
...     d['src'] = link
>>> print(sources)
[{'src': 'link1'}, {'src': 'link2'}, {'src': 'link3'}, {'src': 'link3'}, {'src': 'link4'}, {'src': 'link5'}, {'src': 'link6'}, {'src': 'link6'}, {'src': 'link7'}, {'src': 'link8'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
links = [ 'link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link3', 'link4', 'link5', 'link6', 'link6', 'link7', 'link8', 'link9', 'link10']

sources = [dict(src = ln) for ln in links]
print sources

[{'src': 'link1'}, {'src': 'link2'}, {'src': 'link3'}, {'src': 'link3'}, {'src': 'link4'}, {'src': 'link5'}, {'src': 'link6'}, {'src': 'link6'}, {'src': 'link7'}, {'src': 'link8'}, {'src': 'link9'}, {'src': 'link10'}]

print map(lambda v: dict(src = v), links)
```

or

```
# for python 3
print (list(map(lambda v: dict(src = v), links)))

[{'src': 'link1'}, {'src': 'link2'}, {'src': 'link3'}, {'src': 'link3'}, {'src': 'link4'}, {'src': 'link5'}, {'src': 'link6'}, {'src': 'link6'}, {'src': 'link7'}, {'src': 'link8'}, {'src': 'link9'}, {'src': 'link10'}]
```